# Programs for keeping track of spells

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a spell managing program/app for D&D 3.5e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15777/is-there-a-spell-managing-program-app-for-dd-3-5e)

I have always loved playing spell casters, whether Divine or Arcane. It's nice to know that you do more than swing a sword, but what I dislike about the whole thing is constantly having to keep track of known and memorized/prayed-for spells on paper and having to either look up in the books or copy down every spell when I am not familiar with it.

Is there any software out there that contains a complete spell reference as well as allows you to keep track of a spell list, spells per day, and so on with ease? I'm specifically looking for desktop-computer programs, not smartphone apps.