# Can I use 4th edition Power (Spell) cards in a 3.5e game session?

Tags: dnd-4e, dnd-3.5e, spells, powers

Can I use Dungeons & Dragons 4th Edition Power Cards in a 3.5 game?

I haven't actually looked into the 4e power cards, because I play 3.5e and didn't think spells changed from 3.5 to 4th edition; I just thought overall game play changed.
I'm essentially looking for a shortcut to the whole selection process of picking my daily set of spells as a wizard, instead of having to thumb through an app or physical spell book every time I gain a level or rest in town.

Comment: Have you done any research into what the 4e power cards are and what they do? Why do you think you *can* use them in 3.5e? Alternatively, why do you think you *can't* use them?

Comment: Well the short answer is No I didn't look into the 4e power cards. I play 3.5e i was looking for a shortcut to just pick out spell cards in my preparation as a wizard, instead of having to thumb through an app or physical spell book everytime I gain a level or rest in town. I didn't think spells changed from 3.5 to 4th edition, I just thought overall game play changed... 

Wow I'm new here and really didn't expect an elitist response to a valid question right out of the gate.

Comment: I didn't mean for it to sound like that but we do generally expect people to do at least a little bit of research on the matter *before* asking here. If you hover your mouse over the downvote button you'll see "This question does not show any research effort". You also provided no additional information regarding what you were looking for or why you asked this question. We're not mind readers so without this information we're left to either guess, or ask for clarification, as I did.

Comment: The Stack Exchange is designed to provide actionable solutions to problems people face. Your question originally asked about the viability of a solution (using 4e power cards for 3.5 spells) instead of telling us what the problem was (looking for an easier way to select wizard spells each day). This is sometimes called an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and we ask questions to help clarify the situation so answers can provide solutions to the actual challenge you're facing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Given you said this is for selecting a 3.5 Wizard's daily spell preparations, I can offer the following suggestion.

Every time you level, review your new spells scribed and and spell slot count, and just update 2 or 3 go to lists. The standard I go with is one list for dungeon delving, one for overland travel, and one for downtime/city life. How ever, if your campaign is different, you might want a list for on a boat or a list for when the in-laws are in town... It's your character and you know that's best for them.

That way, you only have to alter a spell list for intel you get ahead of time, and outside of that, you just go with a go to list.

If you need help selecting what spells to scribe or get when you level, I recommend you check out the links attached to [this post](http://community.wizards.com/comment/20798751#comment-20798751). It's a great way to answer the question of "What's a good [school] spell to select for level X?"

As for bringing in 4th ed spell cards... that seems like too much hassle for too little pay off. We need a plan that gives you less work, not more.

Comment: In what way are you answering their question?

Comment: @TheAmusedMuse you shouldn't focus an answer based on just what's in the comments. Comments get deleted and if the main question isn't edited to include this information, *when* the comments get deleted your answer becomes completely irrelevant and unsubstantiated.

Comment: The usual thing to do when you've got a great answer to a different question is to ask and self-answer it as a new question. That said, the question has been updated; adding a sentence addressing the Power Cards would make this complete.

Comment: Thanks SSD, I'm still familiarizing myself with the protocols here. Too often I see things down voted with no reason or fix suggestions offered.

Answer (score 15):

No. They're completely different rules for two rather different games. None of the Powers from D&D 4th edition are part of D&D 3.5e, and those that happen to have similar names to 3.5e spells work completely differently, and reference rules that don't exist in 3.5e.

If you want a spell reference for 3.5e, you're better off cutting and pasting out of the [System Reference Document](http://www.d20srd.org/) and printing out your own, or using one of the many [spell-organisation programs/apps](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15777/is-there-a-spell-managing-program-app-for-dd-3-5e) that exist.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I was hoping that I could... Lol Well I forsee lots of printing and cutting of custom spell cards in my near future. I was was trying to shortcut the whole selection process of picking my daily set of spells. (as you can guess I'm a wizard)

/Sigh...

Comment: @FrankieBigPastaDiaz one of my favorite spell sheet formats is [this one](http://web.archive.org/web/20090904034857/http://www.geocities.com/toytools/dnd) but it's for 3.0. [This page](http://web.archive.org/web/20090916093839/http://www.militaryfocus.com:80/dnd/index.htm) has some similar sheets updated for 3.5E (PDF only). And since the original pages are long gone (archive versions only), I've tried to recreate them in [my page](http://rpg20.com/spells35.php?area=1&reptype=listbylevel&display=print) adding a "print" style. Perhaps some of these suit your needs, like SSD suggests.

Answer (score 0):

**Absolutely not!**
Even the humble fireball does 3d6+int in 4e vs. 1d6/level (max 10d6) in 3.5e

Any similarity is more nostalgic or coincidental than intentional. If you were talking about 1e, 2e, 3e, or even 5e, there might be dozens of spells where you could do this with little (5e) or no (other editions) effort. But 4e is just a completely different animal, like comparing Monopoly and Risk.