# Pathfinder Spells/Psionic Talent Managers

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, psionics, tool-recommendation

Related [Is there a spell managing program app for dnd 3.5](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15777/is-there-a-spell-managing-program-app-for-dd-3-5e)

I am looking for Spell managers that allow me to easily track spells, create spellbooks, and mark if a spell has been used.

I am also using a Psionic class so a manager with the Psionic Talents built in or at least a way to add custom "spells" would be awesome.

Comment: You may have more luck describing more of your requirements here, rather than expecting readers to click through to another question.

Comment: @KRyan The other question is only related because it is the same question but for 3.5. I added it as they are very related not that it contains information required. If I should not have I will remove it.

Comment: Then I think you should probably be a little more detailed in what you’re looking for.